# Неизвестный оператор

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть запрос для ТекДока. В одном из запросов есть:

```
SEARCH_TREE2.STR_ID_PARENT <=> SEARCH_TREE.STR_ID
```

Что этот знак означает, первый раз вижу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NULL-безопасное сравнение. Применяется если один из операндов может быть NULL. В простом сравнении если один из операндов NULL то сравнение вернёт не булево значение а тоже NULL.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, с вашей помощью нашёл:
http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/comparison-operators.html